# number format exception for text filed + wrong format for text field with conditions

Tags: java, mysql

hello I have a problem I want the user to enter a phone number (in a textfield) that isDigit aka numbers not string if it was a string it prints phone format is wrong and if it wasn't 10 digits nor start with 05 it shows also a message 
this is my code for it :

```
 String phone2=phone.getText().trim();
 if(phone2.isEmpty()){//is text field empty 

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Add Phone number !");
           phone.requestFocus();
           return;
       }

               // starts with 05
        String zereofive = phone2.substring(0, 2);

             for(int i=0;i<phone2.length();i++){
                   if (!Character.isDigit(i)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong format for phone");
            phone.requestFocus();
            return;
        } // check length of phone number 
                   else  if (phone2.length() != 10 && !zereofive.equals("05")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter 10 digits for the phone number and starts with 05");
            phone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
             }
```

but it only shows the "Wrong format for phone" message

Another thing is, for the age, I want to catch the number format exception I did like this :

```
    int agee = 0;    // Default if nothing inputed 
               try{
        // AGE
            //is Age text field empty
            String theAge = age.getText().trim();
            if (theAge.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter your age !!");
                age.requestFocus();
                return;
            }


            if (theAge.mat

ches("\\d+")) {
            agee = Integer.parseInt(theAge);
        }
        // only 18 + can register
        if (agee < 18) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't register because you are under 18!");
            age.requestFocus();
            return;
        }}
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter number for age");
        }
```

it only shows here if I entered a string in the text field the " You can't register because you are under 18!" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think have to think through the logic you are using.
To the first problem: 
What is not working in your opinion? Your current logic is:

`If (input empty) {
  "Add Phone number !"
}
if (one input char is not digit) {
  "Wrong format for phone"
} else if (input length != 10 or does not start with "05") {
 "enter 10 digits for the phone number and starts with 05"
}`

So if the input is a char that is not a digit then it will show "Wrong format for phone".

To your second problem:
you set the age = 0 at the beginning.
Then you are using regular expression to check that the input consists only of digits.
If that is not true you never parse the input so NumberformatException will never be thrown (catching it is also not really necessary). You can use following for example

`if (theAge.matches("\\d+")) {
    agee = Integer.parseInt(theAge);
    if (agee < 18) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can't register because you are under 18!");
        age.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
} else {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter number for age");
}`

Comment: okay, i kind of see where are u going with the phone because I checked if its digits  but yet i did the "enter 10 digits for the phone number and starts with 05" which is a  string condition ??? but still i didn't get how to fix it :(

Comment: + i should separate the if of the is diggit and the if for the length and 05 right ? But still isn’t working

Comment: Never mind , i solved the problem thanks for the help i definitely appreciate it